# Cufon and Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, cufon, jquery-chosen

I'm using a Chosen plugin for select element:

```
    <select id="choose" style="width:200px" class="chzn-select">
        <option value="">Option1</option>
        <option value="opt2">Option2</option>
        <option value="opt3">Option3</option>
        <option value="opt4">Option4</option>
    </select>
```

And to activate it:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen()
```

And I need to use cufon for text styling. A am doing this:

```
Cufon.replace('#choose_chzn', { fontFamily: 'HeliosCond', fontWeight:'400' });
```

It works fine, but only till clicking on the select. I think it is because of a 'new' text, that generated on clicking.

My suggest was to use Cufon.refresh() somewhere to reload cufon like this:

```
 $(".chzn-select").chosen().change(Cufon.refresh());
```

But it is not working and I cant figure up how to make it work...
Can anyone help me, please?